# Merge two diffrent json in one json

Tags: node.js, json

I have two json arrays like

```
var json1 = [{"city":"Ahmedabad"}]
var json2 = [{"State":"Gujarat"}]
```

I want them merge in to single arrays

```
var finalObj = [{"city":"Ahmedabad","State":"Gujarat"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two json arrays have the same length, like your example, each json object is a array what includes one object.

You can loop through each item of the json arrays, then merge all of them to a object, finally push it into a array - `finalObj`.

My way use `Object Rest/Spread Properties`, the feature available with `es2018`:

```
var json1 = [{ "city": "Ahmedabad" }]
var json2 = [{ "State": "Gujarat" }]

var finalObj = [];

for (let i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
  finalObj.push({
    ...json1[i],
    ...json2[i]
  })
}

console.log(finalObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using concat() method then the arrays will get merged not the elements then you will get an output somewhat like

```
[{"city":"Ahmedabad"},{"State":"Gujarat"}]
```

If you need an output like this,

```
[{"city":"Ahmedabad","State":"Gujarat"}]
```

then you can implement this,

```
var json1 = [{"city":"Ahmedabad"}];
var json2 = [{"State":"Gujarat"}];

function jsonConcat(destinationObj, sourceObj) {
    for (var key in sourceObj) {
        destinationObj[key] = sourceObj[key];
    }
    return destinationObj;
}

//since json1 &  json2 are arrays you must mention index,
//here index is 0, because it's first json object

var finalObj = jsonConcat(json1[0], json2[0])
console.log(finalObj)
```

**IMPORTANT - This function will replace if similar keys found in both arrays !**

Answer (score 0):

The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

`var finalObj = json1.concat(json2)`

Answer (score 0):

1. merge your array
2. use `reduce` to merge all the items into one object
3. wrap in array

```
var combinedObj = [...json1, ...json2].reduce((acc, obj) => {
  return {
     ...acc,
     ...obj
  }
}, {})
var combinedArr = [...combinedObj]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do merge by using spread / rest operators i.e `...`

```
var json1 = [{"city":"Ahmedabad"}]
var json2 = [{"State":"Gujarat"}]
var result = [...json1, ...json2]; //this will merge them into one.
```

result will be new array as we have merge them into one.
You can also user `concat` method of Javascript. Please refer below for concat -

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_concat